# Why is this string with an outer declaration getting assigned inside the loop and reset outside it?

Tags: c

I'm using this code inside a function to get the shortest and longest string in a file. The length variables and strings are declared outside the loop. The `int` variables are correctly updated inside and outside the loop, but the `char*` variables are only updated correctly inside.

on the last printf statement I get:

```
the string Zulia
 is the longest in a2.txt and has 18 chars

the string Zulia
 is the shortest in a2.txt and has 5 chars
```

What's going on here?

```
fp1 = fopen(fileName, "r"); 

        if (fp1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error while opening file: %s\n",fileName); 
            exit (1);
        } 



            int lengthLongestString=1;
            int lengthShortestString=1000; 

            int lengthActualString=0;

            char *longestString; 
            char *shortestString; 
            char *currentString;



        while (fgets(fileLine,  SIZE_OF_LINE, fp1) != NULL)     
        {

            if(((strcmp(fileLine, "\n") != 0)) && (strcmp(fileLine, "\r\n") != 0)){     //Validates against storing empty lines

                lineas[numeroLineas++] = strdup(fileLine);          


                             lengthActualString=strlen(fileLine); 
                             currentString=fileLine;


                             if (lengthActualString>lengthLongestString){



                                  lengthLongestString = lengthActualString;

                                  longestString=fileLine;
                                  printf("the longest string now is %s \n",longestString);

                 } 

                 else if (lengthActualString<lengthShortestString){

                     lengthShortestString = lengthActualString;


                                 shortestString=fileLine; 
                     printf("the shortest string now is %s \n",shortestString);         
                } // END IF


            }// END IF

          } //END WHILE 

          printf("the string %s is the longest in %s and has %d chars\n",longestString, fileName, lengthLongestString );
          printf("the string %s is the shortest in %s and has %d chars\n",shortestString, fileName, lengthShortestString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`longestString` and `shortestString` are pointers. They **point** somewhere. If you change the contents of *somewhere*, of course, the stuff the pointers point to has changed :-)

You need to allocate memory for `longestString` and `shortestString` (or define them as arrays rather than pointers) and copy the chars there.

Comment: I declared char longestString [] outside and got a compilation error. Where should that call to malloc be made: before the loop or after it?

Comment: To declare a char array outside you need to specify a size `char longestString[1000]`. Of course then you need to check for buffer overflows when copying the chars. `strdup` allocates memory enough for a copy of the original: you should free it before doing a new `strdup` and when you no longer need the data -- or your program leaks memory.

Answer (score 1):

You duplicated the string but forgot to assign that duplicate to your shortest/longest string variable and assigned a pointer to the read buffer instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you assign `shortestString` and `longestString` to `fileLine`.
So you are always printing the value in `fileLine`, which content is that of the last line in you read with fgets.

You should read up on pointers for that.